# Can't keep scroll position in ListView when adding new item on top

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

When I click FloatingAction Button then add new 30 items on top of the ListView

Then ListView auto-scroll to item 61

I want it to keep in item 30

-> Not use reverse

Source code
https://gist.github.com/VNAPNIC/a0c279ab81ff7f7c7120b5c4207b5fe4

Comment: Here, If you will do the setState then its but obvious that it will update the whole UI part. You might have to use StreamBuilder to update the list which can affect to ListView silently.

Answer (score -1):

It is not keeping the scroll in position, but
We can use `controller.jumpTo` on increment to keep the `30` at its position.

```dart
  void _incrementCounter() {
    final startIndex = listItem.length - 1;
    final endIndex = listItem.length + 30;
    for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
      listItem.insert(0, 'Message -------> $i');
    }

    // 50 commig from container +padding
    const itemHeightWithPadding = 50 + 16;

    setState(() {
      // replace 30 with itemLength and set your logic,
      controller.jumpTo(
        (itemHeightWithPadding * 30) + (16 * 8),
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: In my actual project, the height of the widget is flexible.
I can't use Jump because it's good for UI effects

Comment: in that case you use [scroll_to_index](https://pub.dev/packages/scroll_to_index)

Comment: I don't want to use Jump because it isn't good for UI effects